# Howto programmatically generate pretty printed SQL from .net?

Tags: .net, sql, html

Is there a library or source code that's GPL that can turn a SQL statement into beautified HTML?

I'd even settle for some PHP or Java code that I can port to .NET

Tried google, but couldn't find any free sample code.

Comment: Maybe: http://www.dpriver.com/pp/sqlformat.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beautified HTML, similar to how stack overflow highlights code? I've used [SyntakHighlighter](http://code.google.com/p/syntaxhighlighter/) a lot to beautify my code on pages. It's javascript so it might not meet your requirements if you *have* to execute it server-side, but it's certainly one of the more popular ways.

If you can't run client-side then you could always follow their logic for highlighting SQL.

Comment: This is great, but doesn't seem to unwrap the code.. very long statements are still very long statements. I was hoping it would wrap/indent the code too. This is very close to what I needed though, thank you

Comment: It does have a line-wrap option that will wrap at word breaks as needed. It won't split up long words or anything though.

Answer (score 0):

Try [SyntaxHighlighter](http://alexgorbatchev.com/wiki/).

That link is not working for me at the moment. Older version [here](http://code.google.com/p/syntaxhighlighter/).